# Delete suspends RedShift

Tags: system

To save my eyes I have RedShift installed but everytime I delete something it momentarily switches off and back on again.  Is this something I can sort out at this end?

Thanks for any help,
Duncan

Freya 0.3.1 64-bit
Dell Optiplex 745

Answer (score 2):

I had this issue on Loki as well. It is fixable by installing the newest version from [github](https://github.com/jonls/redshift). Click clone or download and download as a zip file. I built it using the instructions in HACKING.md. You'll have to install the prerequisites. Once it was installed I copied the sample ~/.config/redshift.conf from [AUR](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Redshift#Manual_setup). Google the latitude and longitude in your location and change that in the conf file. I also put a ; in front of:

adjustment-method=randr

I was getting an error about randr, and with the manual longitude/latitude setup randr isn't needed. It's a bit of work, and requires making a new .desktop file, easy with an app like alacarte, but redshift doesn't glitch on me now.